# passing data from one fragment to antother

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-spinner

i'm having a fragment called PlacesFragment which has a button that is linked to another fragment called RoutePlanerFragment which has a google map and a spinner to choose places from. When i click the button on the PlacesFragment i would like to have that the route is automatically displayed on the map with having to choose from the spinner.

Here is the code for the button of the PlacesFragment

```
Button btnToRoute = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnToRoute);
    btnToRoute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView){
            RoutePlanerFragment routePlanerFragment = new RoutePlanerFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, routePlanerFragment, routePlanerFragment.getTag()).commit();
```

Thats the map and spinner part of my RoutePlanerFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_route_planer, container, false);

    String[] values =
            {"Route berechnen", "Campus Heilbronn Sontheim", "Campus Schwäbisch Hall", "Campus Künzelsau", "Bildungscampus Nord"};
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.routeSpinner);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return rootView;
    }

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lastKnownLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if(lastKnownLocation == null) {
        lastKnownLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.routePlanerMapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately mMapView.
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady (GoogleMap mMap){
            googleMap = mMap;
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), 15));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude())).title("Du bist hier!").snippet("Text"));
        }
    });

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 100, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            lastKnownLocation = location;
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()), 15));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("Du bist hier!").snippet("Text"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    });

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

              LatLng destination = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

              switch (adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
                  case "Campus Heilbronn Sontheim":
                      destination = new LatLng(49.122123, 9.211115);
                      break;
                  case "Campus Schwäbisch Hall":
                      destination = new LatLng(49.112536,9.743618);
                      break;
                  case "Campus Künzelsau":
                      destination = new LatLng(49.275552, 9.712164);
                      break;
                  case "Bildungscampus Nord":
                      destination = new LatLng(49.147784, 9.217433);
                      break;
                  default: return;
              }

              final LatLng origin = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

              GoogleDirection.withServerKey("AIzaSyD89DmgdibFa3PzNFfGkfB6S7c428Gvo9c")
                      .from(origin)
                      .to(destination)
                      .language(Language.GERMAN)
                      .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                          @Override
                          public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
                              if(direction.isOK()) {

                                  googleMap.clear();

                                  googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), 15));
                                  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude())).title("Du bist hier!").snippet("Text"));

                                  Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
                                  Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(0);

                                  String wayPointHtml = "";
                                  for (Step step : leg.getStepList()) {
                                      Log.d("BESCHREIBUNG", step.getHtmlInstruction().toString());
                                      wayPointHtml += step.getHtmlInstruction().toString() + "<br/><br/>";
                                  }

                                  WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.routeWebView);
                                  webView.loadData(wayPointHtml, "text/html", "utf-8");

                                  Info distanceInfo = leg.getDistance();
                                  Info durationInfo = leg.getDuration();

                                  TextView routeInfo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.routeInfo);
                                  routeInfo.setText("Entfernung: " + distanceInfo.getText() + "Dauer: " + durationInfo.getText());

                                  ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = leg.getDirectionPoint();

                                  PolylineOptions polylineOptions = DirectionConverter.createPolyline(getContext(), directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED);
                                  googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);


                              } else {
                              }
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {

                          }
                      });
          }

          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

          }
      }
    );

    return rootView;
}
```

The values that are displayed on the fragment_places.xml are stored in the DummyContent.java

This the fragment_places.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.ensartok.rossappensar.PlacesFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="417dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Campus Sontheim"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/street"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Max-Planck-Straße 39"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zipplace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="74081 Heilbronn"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:text="Route berechnen"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And that`s the part with the values inside DummyContent.java

```
public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

static {
    DummyItem standort1 = new DummyItem("1", "HHN Campus Sontheim", "Max-Planck-Straße 39","74081", "Heilbronn","49.122123", "9.211115");
    addItem(standort1);
    DummyItem standort2 = new DummyItem("2", "Campus Schwäbisch Hall", "Ziegeleiweg 4","74523", "Schwäbisch Hall","49.112536", "9.743618");
    addItem(standort2);

    DummyItem standort3 = new DummyItem("3",
            "Reinhold-Würth-Hochschule – Campus Künzelsau",
            "Daimlerstraße 35","74653",
            "Künzelsau",
            "49.275552", "9.712164");
    addItem(standort3);

    DummyItem standort4 = new DummyItem("4",
            "Bildungscampus Nord",
            "Bauteil N / Nr. 12","74076",
            "Heilbronn",
            "49.147784", "9.217433");
    addItem(standort4);
}
```

Sorry that the question involves so much code, but i guess that it's needed for you guys to be able to answer my question.

So just once again.
If you press the button on the PlacesFragment you are getting to the RoutePlanerFragment and now i would like that the route is automatically to the destination that i pressed the button in the PlacesFragment.

Hopefully you guys get what i'm trying to explain

Comment: You want to send chunks of data from one fragment to another fragment . Right ?

Comment: Don;t paste too much code.. Where you feel that there might be some mistake then only post code..it's becomes ambiguous

Comment: I would like to send Lat and Lng, like "49.122123", "9.211115", to the RoutePlanerFragment so that the included map show the route from my current position to "49.122123", "9.211115" directly. Sorry that i posted that much code. i wasn`t sure what you guys need for an answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi As per my Understanding, You can send data from one fragment to another fragment by this

**This will add data to bundle**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("latitude", latitude);
bundle.putString("longitude", longitude);
bundle.putString("board_id", board_id);
Fragment_A fragment = new Fragment_A();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**This will fetch data from Fragment_A**

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
String latitude =  getArguments().getString("latitude")
```

You can also send ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for your qucik help. i guess i have to add the first code part to my code for the button. Colud you tell where to add the second code part? I guess inside the RoutePlanerFragment code (the second code i posted), am i right?

Comment: I think you had made a DummyItem model class which holds setter and getter fro values field.. Make an ArrayList<DummyItems> = new ArrayList<>; and  send this arralyList through setArgument and get it by Next Fragment.